# Why does my game crash on entering the realm?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

I'm using Minecraft 1.13.1, and my game crashes on entering the realm.

This is my crash output:

```
18:37:30    launcher    Preparing to launch minecraft client for 1.13.1 
18:37:31    launcher    Checking installations. 
18:37:31    launcher    Minecraft client 1.13.1 is ready to start. 
18:37:31    launcher    Starting! 
18:37:31    launcher    Using default game log configuration client-1.12.xml (outputs XML) 
18:37:32    cfs Setting user: InternetDownHelp 
18:37:34    cfv Skipping bad option: lastServer: 
18:37:34    cfs LWJGL Version: 3.1.6 build 14 
18:37:36    vh  Reloading ResourceManager: Default 
18:37:36    dgq Starting up SoundSystem... 
18:37:36    dgq Initializing No Sound 
18:37:36    dgq (Silent Mode) 
18:37:37    dgq OpenAL initialized. 
18:37:37    dgq Preloading sound minecraft:sounds/ambient/underwater/underwater_ambience.ogg 
18:37:37    dgq Sound engine started 
18:37:59    launcher     
20:37:59    monitor Process crashed with exit code -805306369
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to find answers for Minecraft specific, but for other programs, the exit code -805306369 suggests corrupt data. Try reinstalling Minecraft and using a new `.minecraft` folder (of course back up your worlds and settings before you do that).